# Convert Chinese date to English

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to convert `2017年12月27日` to English date. To convert I was trying:

```
moment("2017年12月27日", 'DDMMMMYYYY, HH:mm:ss', 'zh-cn').locale('en').toISOString();
```

but it gives out nothing but `null`. What could be the reason for this? How can I convert it to an english date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input format string is wrong. It should match with the sequence you gave (like year first, then month, etc.).

You should include special characters to it (if any), too.

```js
console.log(moment("2017年12月27日", 'YYYY年MM月DD日', 'en', true).toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please note that your snippet does not work (you loaded moment via `http` instead of `https`). Your format token parameter is incorrect,you used `年` instead of `月`, this will fail in [strict mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/)

Comment: @VincenzoC Sorry, I'm not familiar with Chinese, I copy-pasted from OP's provided string.

Answer (score 1):

Your format parameter is incorrect, `'DDMMMMYYYY, HH:mm:ss'` does not match with your input (`2017年12月27日`).

`2017年12月27日` is not in ISO 8601 format (since it includes chineses letters instead of `-`), but it is recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parser because by defaults it uses [forgiving mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/forgiving-mode/).

Special characters could be escaped using square brackets `[]`, as shown in  [Escaping characters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters) section of the docs.

```js
var fmt = moment.localeData('zh-cn').longDateFormat('LL'); // YYYY年M月D日
var m = moment("2017年12月27日", fmt, 'zh-cn');
console.log( m.locale('en').toISOString() );

var m2 = moment("2017年12月27日", 'YYYY[年]M[月]D[日]', 'zh-cn', true);
console.log( m2.locale('en').toISOString() );
console.log( m2.locale('en').format('LLLL') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

In my sample code, I've used [`localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat()` to get chinese specific format token.